# Missing files in Android Studio project

Tags: git, android-studio

I have issue with missing files from my Android Studio project. What I have done is:

I have been working on my app and than I have exported .apk file, closed Android Studio, tomorrow when I opened it again files are missing. There is no Java classes or packages or even `build.gradle` file although in my `workspace.xml` I can see paths of classes.

I have version control integrated but I didn't commit last changes which I made how can I return my project back?
Also my projects are stored on external SSD and I have many other projects which are loading and working fine but issue is with this one.

I Google it, found some similar cases and tried:

- **Sync with Gradle Files**
- **Invalidate caches and restart**
- **Import project**

None of these steps worked. This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: What's the output when you run `git status` in your terminal? Are your "missing" files there?

Comment: Hey @PPartisan `git status` showed me `new files` which I created or in which I made changes but also showed me `deleted files` don't get it I didn't delete anything

Comment: Are the "deleted" (removed?) files the one's you're missing?

Comment: Yes those files are missing. Basically all is missing `app` folder is empty as you can see from screenshot.

Comment: It can be a little difficult to explain git commands over text, but you can try `git stash` initially and see whether that restores your files. If it doesn't work, anything in staging will be added to your stash list and you can revert it with `git stash pop`. So, try that first.

Comment: Okay it restores some files but I as I could see there are no latest updates and changes I made in project. Files don't contain latest changes I made in them.

Comment: Without being able to look at the repo and pick through it, I think you're just going to have to see all the differences (you can press `Ctrl + K` in your IDE to view them) and undo/redo whichever ones you need.

Comment: @PPartisan that action shows files unfortunately not latest changes I made in them. Thanks for trying to help I really appreciate that.

Comment: When you use the `Import Project` option on JetBrains tools (IntelliJ/Android Studio); it will only show file matching the type of project. So, in this case, most probably all the Java files but not any other. Try the `Open` option instead of `Import Project` this should show all the files.

Comment: Are the changes stored on disk or in the VCS? If they are, it's just an AS problem and you can ignore the rest of this comment. However, if you lost the changes and didn't store it and want those back, you're slightly more screwed. Invalidating caches and restarting **deletes** local history(the "integrated VCS" - stores different versions of files at whatever metric the IDE is set up to use, and it usually saves when it feels like it),which means you cannot recover the files like that. And if the changes aren't commited to the VCS either, you're out of options unless you manually backed it up

Comment: @Zoe true that. I had no options left but to rewrite what I have lost. I don't know does anyone had similar issue but yesterday this thing happened in another project which doesn't have Version Control integrated, fortunately I had a backup. But this starts to frighten me a bit.